# Error while choosing range for Excel chart using matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, charts, range

I have an Excel file with to sheets. First about 30 columns and 20.000 rows. 2nd about 10 columns and 2 rows. Each with a header.

No, there are less than 66.000 rows in the file I work with and I use .xlsx files, so it's not that problem. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range) might be related but didn't help for me

The goals for the script were:

- Automaticly creating a Chart in an already Existing `.xlsx` file using Matlab
- Easy way to choose Range, X- and Y-Values (by sheet and column) freely
- applicable to all sizes on `.xlsx` files. (up to 20.000 rows and 50 columns and several sheets)

---

In this **Code** range is set to the following: *X -> column B* , *Y -> column H - P* , the sheet is 'sheet1' called *'Tabelle1'*

```matlab
%%%%% general Code to insert a Chart in Excel using Matlab %%%%%
%% start Excel and open Workbook
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\...\Test.xlsx');
%% makes the created sheet visible
excel.Visible = true;
%% add 1. Chart
chart1 = wb.Charts.Add;
%% set source data 
chart1.SetSourceData(wb.Worksheets.Item('Tabelle1').Range('$B:$B, $H:$P')); % 'Tabelle1' is the german equal to sheet1, my excel is german
%% Name chart sheet
chart1.Name = '1. TestChart';
%% Set chart title,  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196832.aspx
chart1.HasTitle = true;
chart1.ChartTitle.Text = 'Test Title';
%% Set chart types,  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837417.aspx
chart1.ChartType = 'xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers';
%% Set chart legend, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821884.aspx
chart1.HasLegend = true;
%% Set Axes Titles
chart1.Axes(1).HasTitle = true;
chart1.Axes(1).AxisTitle.Text = 'Time [s]'; % XAxes
chart1.Axes(2).HasTitle = true;
chart1.Axes(2).AxisTitle.Text = 'Temperature[°C]'; %YAxes
%% add 2nd chart
chart2 = wb.Charts.Add([], chart1); %place after chart1
chart2.SetSourceData(wb.Worksheets.Item('Tabelle1').Range('$B:$B, $Q:$Q'));
% ... same procedure as above

%% use to quit all open Excel processes
% excel.Quit;
```

this Error occurs:

> Error using Interface.000208D8_0000_0000_C000_000000000046/Range
>
> Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC
>
> Error in CodeTestmy (line 13)
>   chart1.SetSourceData(wb.Worksheets.Item('Tabelle1').Range('$B:$B, $H:$P'));

I'm pretty sure, that this code works just fine and I can't explain the error.

---

Can you please help me to find out, were the error comes from to finaly solve the problem.

Here are the download Links (Google Drive) to the `.m script` and `.xlsx file` used

Thanks

*Kilian Weber*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on Worksheet.range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range)

Comment: For sure I already read this post, but none of the answers work for me^^